# Php mysql friends list - getting back a list of names from sever not working

Tags: php, mysql

Php mysql- getting back a list of names from sever not working if list contains more that one entry. I'm thinking it this line $data .= "bffname=".$row->bffname; any advice would be most sincerely appreciated.

One name in the list

> gets bffname=graham

two names in the list

> gets bffname=grahambffname=bobby

PHP

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
$dbTable = "`".$username."_Friend`";


// getting data
$data = "";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbTable." ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $data .= "bffname=".$row->bffname;

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `$dbTable = "\`".$_POST['username']."_Friend\`";` is a very bad idea.

Comment: You're storing each friend list in individual tables? That's unusual.

Comment: You should consider using PDO [see prior stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496). And you should validate the POST variable.

Comment: "$dbTable = "`".$_POST['username']."_Friend`";" I am really new to php, and this is the only solution I could find that works for my test project

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: there will only be 4 friends total

Comment: there is no error it just I'm not sure and cant find a simple way to separat the names bffname=graham bffname=bobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your question.
The question is a bit indirect.

I guess you want to know how to disply the names one per line, right?

I've appended a new line (\n):

```
$data .= "bffname=".$row->bffname."\n";
```

I guess a HTML break would also work for you:

```
$data .= "bffname=" . $row->bffname . "<br>";
```

Comment: Maybe this basic MySQL example is of help, too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php Maybe you want to display a table?
See the comment // Printing results in HTML